# return to client on bad scope

Tags: asp.net-core, openid-connect, openiddict

Is there a way to make OpenIddict redirect back to client application with error status of `invalid_scope` for an invalid scope error?

Today it interrupts the flow by displaying this at the authorize endpoint:

```
error:invalid_scope
error_description:The specified 'scope' is invalid.
error_uri:https://documentation.openiddict.com/errors/ID2052
```

But the [specification](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#section-4.1.2.1) says:

> If the resource owner denies the access request or if the request fails for reasons other than a missing or invalid redirection URI, the authorization server informs the client by adding the following parameters to the query component of the redirection URI...

Is there some configuration option I missed, or a way to hook an event to override this behavior?

EDIT: there is an event hook but it apparently happens before the validation of the redirect URI, so it would be dangerous to take this approach.

```cs
options.AddEventHandler<ApplyAuthorizationResponseContext>( builder =>
{
    builder.UseInlineHandler( responseContext =>
    {
        if ( responseContext.Error != null
            && responseContext.Error == "invalid_request"
            && ( responseContext.Response.Error == "invalid_scope" || ( responseContext?.Response?.ErrorDescription?.Contains( "scope is not allowed" ) ?? false ) )
        )
        {
            responseContext.ResponseMode = "query";
            var issuer = responseContext?.BaseUri?.AbsoluteUri ?? string.Empty;
            var state = responseContext?.Request?.State ?? string.Empty;
            //DON'T DO THIS. REDIRECT URI MIGHT BE INVALID
            responseContext!.RedirectUri = $"{responseContext?.Request?.RedirectUri}?state={HttpUtility.UrlEncode( state )}&iss={HttpUtility.UrlEncode( issuer )}";
        }
        return default;
    } );
} );
```

Comment: according to the section you shared, returning error message looks like the expected behavior when we used invalid scope. And per my understanding, we usually require `scope` when we try to generate the access token, do you mean you got issue when login in, and you want to change the symptom to "redirect to your specific page" instead of "show error message in the browser"?

Comment: Right, an error message will be shown for invalid scope, but the question is *where* will it be shown? On the OpenIddict side, or on the client (RP) side? The spec seems to indicate that the authorization server should redirect back to the client (RP) and let the client decide how to present the error.

Comment: I can't repro the issue in my side yet so I'm not sure about it, however I'm afraid that the error is inside the request query appending in the redirect url so that the issue should be able to be handled by the client. Anyway it's better to see the symptom first then let's say how to deal with it.... I only test with Azure AD which is also based on OIDC but I didn't repro the issue right now..